# Find the number of active connections per database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

I have a drupal application that uses the database named db1. Each time a drupal request is sent, a new connection to database will be established.So after a certain number of conneections has reached the site turns offline showing the following error:

User db1 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections.

So my aim is to close the database connection and thereafter avoiding the offline error. For this I need to find the number of active connections made to my database.I have tried with the SHOW PROCESSLIST command. But it is not showing the number of connections.

Is there any method to find the number of database connections made to a mysql database?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW STATUS LIKE 'threads_connected';`

Although if your Drupal (or the webserver to be precise) is not closing connections automatically after each request, there's probably something that is not configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried this but it is not showing me the actual number of users connected to my database. In the current scenario, drupal application does not close the active connections and I am trying to close it explicitly. For that I need to monitor the website load before and after closing the connection. Or is there any tool to perform load testing?

Comment: There are several, but in your place I'd start looking into why is PHP not closing connections. Are you using persistent connections by any chance? If yes - then don't. Move to non-persistent connections.